# Shortcut to calculate sums of floor functions, correct or no?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My question is regarding the Legendre's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Applications) (in it we calculate exponent of prime in n! where n is any natural number)

according to legendre's formula,

power of $x$ in $n! = \lfloor n/x\rfloor + \lfloor n/x^2\rfloor + ... + \lfloor n/x^k\rfloor$ where $x^k \leq n \lt x^{(k + 1)}$

Is it same as if I calculate like this

$y_1 = \lfloor n/x\rfloor$

$y2 = \lfloor y_1/x\rfloor $

$y_3 = \lfloor y_2/x\rfloor$

...

$y_n = \lfloor y_{n-1}/x\rfloor$

then add all y, that is, exponent of $x$ in $n! = y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + \dots + y_n$

```
Is the first method (Legendre's formula) same as second method?
I am asking this because when I calculate by hand, second method will be faster to calculate

If both methods are same, please provide an explanation too :)
```

Comment: Yes, it is the same. For example, if you know $y_1$ and $y_2$, then $x y_2\le y_1<x(y_2+1)$, and therefore $x^2y_2\le x y_1<x^2(y_2+1)$. Also $xy_1\le n<x(y_1+1)$. Here $x(y_1+1)$ is the smallest integer divisible by $x$ that is larger than $xy_1$. Therefore $x^2(y_2+1)\ge x(y_1+1)$, and we can conclude that $n\le x^2(y_2+1)$. In other words $y_2=\lfloor\dfrac n{x^2}\rfloor$ etc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for verification (but I am facing difficulty to understand the proof you provided...)

Comment: @AmanJain For any integer $x \gt 1$, compare what happens when using Legendre's formula and your method with $n$ expressed in base $x$, i.e., $n = \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}x^{i}$, where $0 \le a_{i} \le x - 1$.

Comment: It was not really a proof. Basically trying to explain why $y_k=\lfloor n/x^k\rfloor$, forcing $n$ into the interval $[y_kx^k, (y_k+1)x^j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using a particular case of the following result ( for each summand) :

Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be positive integers and $\alpha$ a positive real.

Then $\lfloor \alpha  / (a_1a_2 \dots a_n) \rfloor$ is the same as the final term of the sequence $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n$ when $\alpha_0 = \alpha$ and $\alpha_{i+1} = \lfloor \alpha_i/a_i\rfloor $.

Proof: Write $\alpha$ as $k(a_1\dots a_n) + \beta$ with $\beta\in [0,1)$.

We must prove $\alpha_n$ is equal to $k$.

We can prove that each $\alpha_i$ is of the form $k(a_{i+1}\dots a_n) + \beta_i$ with $\beta_i \in [0,1)$ by induction.